# React-Native + Firebase : How to handle realtime updates

Tags: javascript, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I am using react native + firebase. I need to update my list of docs everytime there is a new doc. so I found information about "real time updates" and using "onSnapshot":

```
let items = [];

firebase.firestore().collection("docs").onSnapshot(function(results) {

            results.forEach((doc) => {
                const item = doc.data()
                if (item) {
                    items.push(item);
                }
              });


    }, function(error) {
       console.log(error)
    })
```

If I return a value onSnapshot will run only once the idea is to keep it listening to changes, how should I implement that?

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're trying to do or what isn't working the way you expect.

Answer (score 3):

I understand that you are using the React Native Firebase package (https://rnfirebase.io/)

You are correct, there is a function that listens to changes on the database in real time (for example, the number of likes on a post).

Check the docs here: [Firestore Real Time Changes](https://rnfirebase.io/firestore/usage#realtime-changes)

This is the proposed code on the docs for listening to this type of changes:

```
function User({ userId }) {
  useEffect(() => {
    const subscriber = firestore()
      .collection('Users')
      .doc(userId)
      .onSnapshot(documentSnapshot => {
        console.log('User data: ', documentSnapshot.data());
      });

    // Stop listening for updates when no longer required
    return () => subscriber();
  }, [userId]);
}
```

In my experience with React Native Firebase, the real time changes work pretty well. Make sure your code is as explained in the official docs and you will be good to go.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

import firestore from '@react-native-firebase/firestore';

export const fetchUserData = () => {
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

```
const unsubscribe = firestore()
  .collection('Users')
  .onSnapshot(snapshot => {
    let changes= snapshot.docChanges();
    changes.forEach(change=>{
    console.log("change Happen",change.doc.data());
  });

  })

  .catch((error) => {
    console.log('Error fetching data:', error);
    reject([]);
  });




// Return the unsubscribe function to clean up the subscription if needed
return unsubscribe;
```

});
};

// This file only contains the fetchUserData function

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).